# Replicating Typeracer

Tags: django

I have been trying to replicate typeracer which is an online platform to increase typing speed and also I am a beginner in django.

I have three models named, Players(is an abstraction of the default user model and holds info of all the registered users), Posts(contains all the passages that are available to practice typing), UserPost(contains id of all the posts which are used and the id of Account which used it).

My question is how can I implement multiple games. For example, suppose A and B are playing together on one game, and at the same time C,and D want to start a new game identified by another game url, also again at the same time E, F, G, H want to start another game identified by different game url to compete just amongst themselves at the same time.

If I am not able to make myself clear, please check 
[this](http://play.typeracer.com/) and go on to race your friends, and just click on invite people to join! You will get what I mean.

How to do implement this.? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to create a new model named games and make a slug field called url, it can act as pk too.